# Python - How to detect when user opens another file inside Blender?

Tags: python

Edit: I think I have found what I was looking for `bpy.app.handlers.load_post`, but will leave it open for maybe better suggestions.

I have a class variable that is stored in `bpy.types.Scene.my_class`, which I access with `context.scene.my_class`.

The problem I am having is that I need this class to be deleted and recreated when the user opens another .blend file from within Blender. The only way I can think of is to store `path + file_name` to the current .blend and check it before running the rest of my script to decide if `my_class` needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Is it a property or some "monkey patch" arrangement like `bpy.types.Scene.foo = 2` ?

Comment: @batFINGER It is a monkey patch for sure, holds a custom class with internal data (numpy arrays, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Using a handler to remove `my_class`:

```
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def handler_new_scene(scene):
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_class
```

I think `del scene.my_class` will work also, or `scene.my_class = None` if still need to have the attribute.

In the register function I add my function to the load_pre handler, which will run before a new scene is loaded:

```
bpy.app.handlers.load_pre.append(handler_new_scene)
```